# Using memoryView to manipulate a large buffer

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, memoryview

My application requires a C library. At some point, the library provides a pointer to a large buffer filled with binary structures. I do not want to copy from/to the large buffer.
I would like to manipulate the buffer through a memoryView of a bytearray class.
In Python3.4, I tried to feed the C pointer into ctypes.PyMemoryView_FromMemory but it seems to return an Int object.
What's the best way to set the address of the buffer into the memoryView of a bytearray?
 If possible, I prefer not to use Cython.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a `ctypes.Array` or `ctypes.Structure` subclass. Whatever definition you decide on to access the buffer, the type has a `from_address` constructor to create an instance from a pointer (as an integer address).

Comment: @eryksun Maybe there's something I don't understand. I prefer a memoryView because it has a better set of operators and methods (slicing, cast, tolist, etc). ctypes types can't do very much.

Comment: Slicing a ctypes array returns a list, which depending on the array type and dimension could be a list of arrays, other ctypes types, or built-in Python objects. You can also create another array view (not a copy) using either pointers or `from_buffer` (with an optional byte offset). You can cast through a pointer dereference or using `ctypes.cast()`.